# Identify user with a VPN connection within the network

Tags: vpn, log-analysis

I know of a user within my network who initiated a VPN connection within my network. What are ways I'll be able to find out the identity of user, searching port numbers? specific protocol established?

I am Using IBM qradar for monitoring a medium sized organisation.

Comment: Find out who owns the originating IP address and corresponding mac address

Comment: The thing is I don't know the originating IP that's the problem. I just now from CISCO Umbrella that someone from the company has accessed a Hola VPN.  And I need to find out the originating IP

Comment: @lucy so, what information do you have in your log? it sounds like you're looking at a tabulated report, or some sort of dashboard ... there must be underlying observations that you can access?

Comment: There's not enough information here. We have no idea what your network looks like, how users gain access, what devices they are using etc.